# FlatList Pagination with ReactHooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I have simple list that needs pagination when scrolling to bottom. currently initial data array works without any problem. but the problem comes when i want to append next array to existing one. `numberList` gets replaced with new array. but not sure how to append to it.
Below is my implementation.

```
export default function Numbers({ route, navigation }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { url } = route.params;

  const numberList = Object.values(
    useSelector(state => state.numberReducer.numbers),
  );

  const [count, setCount] = useState(2);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('URL ', url);
    dispatch(numberActions.requestNumbers(url));
  }, []);


  const fetchMore = () => {
    console.log('Fetch More');
    setCount(count + 1);
    const newUrl = "Another URL depending on the Count number";

    /** This also gets fired. problem is New Number list gets replaced to numberList. dont know how to append **/
    dispatch(numberActions.requestNumbers(newUrl));
  };

  const renderNumber = numberObject => {
    return (
      <Text>
        {numberObject.item.title}
      </Text>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <FlatList
        data={numberList}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.title}
        renderItem={renderNumber}
        horizontal={false}
        onEndReached={fetchMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

My Reducer

```
const initialState = {
  numbers: [],
};

export const numberReducer = createReducer(initialState, {
  [types.NUMBER_RESPONSE](state, action) {
    return {
      ...state,
      numbers: action.response,
    };
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the problem and if you can provide a full example that I can ran i could try to help you more.

Assuming that after calling to fetchMore will end up in your reducer in types.NUMBER_RESPONSE with action.response containing the numbers to add, It seems like you are overriding the old numbers.

You can try to change your reducer instead of

```
 return {
      ...state,
      numbers: action.response,
    };
```

Try

```
 return {
      ...state,
      numbers: [...state.numbers, ...action.response]
    };
```

Or anything other that will add the numbers to the old state.numbers

Comment: Correct.  `numbers: [...state.numbers, ...action.response]` this works. problem is, then how can i go back to initial state? do i need to fire another action to  make reducer again to `numbers: []` ?

Comment: You can split it to two different actions one that will add numbers to the state and another one that will reset it / set it to specific value (and then send [])